# Magento upgrade via Magento Connect fails

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce

I tried to upgrade our shopsoftware from Ver. 1.3.2.3 to 1.4.1.0 and I used the Magento Connect Manager. It loads all the files and said they has been installed, but they are not. Under “downloader/pearlib/download/” are all these files. Have I forgotten anything or is that maybe a bug in our customized shopversion?

I’m searching for days and hope, someone can help me here.

Comment: Did you do this on your live site or on test/dev?

Answer (score 0):

I'm in your shoes as well. I've got an upgrade to do as well, and trying to do it automatically didn't work out well at all.

Here's the only upgrade path I've gotten to work:

1. Install a fresh copy of 1.4.1.0
2. Backup 1.3.2.3 via Magento
3. Move media files from 1.3.2.3
4. Bring skin over, convert to 1.4.1.0's new requirements
5. Bring modules over - turn error reporting on, and check for issues (there were a ton with ours)

Good luck. I'm still having some issues with ours :(

Comment: As far as I can tell, this might cause issues with the database and any conversion scripts that need to be run as part of the upgrade. Can you confirm whether this is the case?

Comment: I tried the straight conversion and had more issues with the conversion scripts. Not sure if I did something wrong when I took that route, but there were a ton of errors coming from the sql folders in core

Comment: Errors creeping from the SQL folders mean that there's definitely some database problems in the upgradation.

Comment: @KC yeah, and I haven't been able to get through those. I got pulled off of the upgrade because it required more time than we thought to get it going correctly. I'd like to give it a shot again, though.